# Is there a way to run arbitrary code on objects created in a R Shiny app?

Tags: r, console, shiny

My users would like to run some R scripts using the objects that my Shiny App creates. E.g. if my app creates a new data frame, they would like to run their own analysis using the new data frame.

Is there a way to do that?
Maybe some console-like (interactive) feature in R Shiny?

I found this [Access/use R console when running a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020636/access-use-r-console-when-running-a-shiny-app), but wondering if there is any other way to do it besides building your own server.

Any input is great appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a data frame available to the user in the global environment after running the app, you can use `assign()`. The following example uses the logic of a shiny widget that can be added as an [add-in to RStudio](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/):

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("name","Name of data set"),
    numericInput("n","Number observations", value = 10),
    actionButton("done","Done")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    thedata <- reactive({
      data.frame(V1 = rnorm(input$n),
                 V2 = rep("A",input$n))
    })

    observeEvent(input$done,{
      assign(input$name, thedata(), .GlobalEnv)
      stopApp()
    })
  }
)
```

Keep in mind though that your R thread is continuously executing when a shiny app is running, so you only get access to the global environment after the app stopped running. This is how packages with a shiny interface deal with it.

If you want users to be able to use that data frame while the app is running, you can add a code editor using eg [shinyAce](https://www.r-bloggers.com/ace-code-editor-in-shiny-shinyace/). A short example of a shiny App using shinyAce to execute arbitrary code:

```
library(shinyAce)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    numericInput("n","Number observations", value = 10),
    aceEditor("code","# Example Code.\n str(thedata())\n#Use reactive expr!"),
    actionButton("eval","Evaluate code"),
    verbatimTextOutput("output")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    thedata <- reactive({
      data.frame(V1 = rnorm(input$n),
                 V2 = rep("A",input$n))
    })

    output$output <- renderPrint({
      input$eval
      return(isolate(eval(parse(text=input$code))))
    }) 
  }
)
```

But the package comes with some nice examples, so take a look at those as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a very basic console on Shiny. It is based on Dean Attali's code [here](http://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/#run-arbitrary-code). The idea is to execute arbitrary code from a `textInput` with the `eval` function using the same environment that shiny is using. To test the idea, the variable `myDat` was created inside the server function and can be used by the user. It should also work with other objects created later. I also enabled the "Enter" key to press the [Run] button using JavaScript, so you don't need click on the button.

It is recommended to enable this console only to trusted users, it is a complete open access to any R command and can be potentially a serious security issue.

```R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # enable the <enter> key to press the [Run] button
  tags$script(HTML(
    '$(document).keyup(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#run").click();
      }
     });'
  )),
  textInput("expr", label = "Enter an R expression",
            value = "myDat"),
  actionButton("run", "Run", class = "btn-success"),
  div( style = "margin-top: 2em;",
    uiOutput('result')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shinyEnv <- environment()

  myDat <- head(iris)

  r <- reactiveValues(done = 0, ok = TRUE, output = "")
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    shinyjs::hide("error")
    r$ok <- FALSE
    tryCatch(
      {
        r$output <- isolate(
          paste(
            capture.output(
              eval(parse(text = input$expr), envir = shinyEnv)
            ),
            collapse = '\n'
          )
        )
        r$ok <- TRUE
      }
      ,
      error = function(err) {
        r$output <- err$message
      }
    )
    r$done <- r$done + 1
  })

  output$result <- renderUI({
    if (r$done > 0 ) { 
      content <- paste(paste(">", isolate(input$expr)), r$output, sep = '\n')
      if (r$ok) {
        pre(content)
      } else {
        pre( style = "color: red; font-weight: bold;", content)
      }
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```